# How can I make bugs for product backlog items in TFS Preview (Azure Hosted TFS)?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I'm new to team foundation server, and more specifically, the TFS preview (Azure Hosted TFS) on [tfspreview.com](http://tfspreview.com).

I find it strange that when I add a bug work item and link it as a child to one of my user stories, it is being shown individually in the system as a "container" that can contain several tasks in my scrum board as shown below.

[image]

*By the way, the bug is the one with the red "circle" around it.*

As you can see, the bug has a plus icon next to it allowing me to add tasks for the bug. But why would that be needed? In which scenario is that handy? For me, there are always 2 tasks needed for every bug found (and my developers are aware of this).

- Build an automated test to recreate the bug if possible.
- Fix the bug itself, making the above tests pass.

So how can I make my bug be contained within my "General: Translations" product backlog item, making it movable (as a task) from "To-do" to "In-progress", and from there to "Completed"? Right now it acts like a category for tasks, which is not at all appropriate for me.

Comment: I am assuming you are using the Scrum template?  Bugs are considered product backlog items and that template is configured to show those on the right side.  Tasks are only shown on the Task Board for the Scrum Template.

Comment: Which template should I be using then?

Comment: This is idiotic - Why does the Scrum template not show bugs on the board underneath the PBI parent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Instead of my comment above, I'll add this as an answer since I received confirmation from the product team that this is the answer.*

I am assuming you are using the Scrum template? Bugs are considered product backlog items and that template is configured to show those on the right side. Tasks are only shown on the Task Board for the Scrum Template.

At the moment with TFS Preview, you are unable to change the process template of an existing team project.  If you would like to use the MSF Agile template, you will want to create a new team project.

Answer (score 2):

As TFS Azure is still in limited preview you will not have much luck finding resources here because only a very small set of users have access to TFS Azure. Your best best is to contact Azure TFS team either forums or directly contacting via TFSadmin.

[More info]

As you are using TFS preview, so its not customizable in TFSPreview and only task shows up in “To Do” which can be dragged to different states. No other type can be used.

You can directly to post your questions here:

- http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/TFService/threads

Comment: The documentation for MS VS Scrum 2.0 is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff731587(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: I think his best bet is to learn to understand the template he's using. This issue is not specific to the TFS preview.